# IBM Management Center for WebSphere Commerce: The user account is disabled

Tags: websphere, websphere-commerce

I try to access to Management Center with my account but this show an error that said "The user account is disabled. Contact your site administrator regarding your access". How can I enable the user account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to documentation:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v5r6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.esupport.doc/html/Runtime/swg21178298.html

should work for version 6 and 7 also.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use WebSphere Commmerce Org Admin.   Seems like you got the answer already.

Answer (score 0):

SQL to enable useraccount -

update userreg set status = 1 where logonid='(login id)';